# In Android, how to display alert dialog with square corners like in Google Maps?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, alert, android-alertdialog

How can I display an AlertDialog in Android that looks like the one in Google Maps application (square corners)? I attach the image below.

Is it available out of the box (some property or theme) or do I have to style it myself?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to display a dialog in general? Or, are you asking how to get a list with an `>` on the right side of some arbitrary elements?

Comment: @dobracey: I ask about square corners only. The default alert dialog has rounded corners, it doesn't look good in my app. I'd prefer square corners like in Google Maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this tutorial. hope it will help you, as it does says that it may cause problems

http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/271

hope this is what you're looking for (the first image is, I believe, what you're after)